# Why is this not controlling my shift registers?

Tags: arduino

this has been cooking my brain for hours. I just don't get what I'm doing wrong. The code seems to be wrong when entering the "if (seperate == ..)" loop. So I want to read from serial, apply the value to the first register, then read and apply to the second register, then read and apply to the third register and finally "reset" the counter(and start over).

```
#define data_r 2 //data input red register
#define data_g 3 //data input green register
#define data_b 4 //data input blue register
#define clock_r 6 //clock input red register
#define clock_g 7 //clock input green register
#define clock_b 8 //clock input blue register
#define clock 9 //clock pin for all three registers
#define reset 5
int seperate;
int val;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(clock, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock_r, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock_g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock_b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data_r , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data_g , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data_b , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(reset, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(reset, LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(reset, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int seperate_mod = seperate % 3;
    Serial.print("seperate_mod = ");
    Serial.println(seperate_mod);
    if (seperate_mod == 0) {

        val = Serial.parseInt();
        shiftOut(data_r, clock_r, MSBFIRST, val);

    } else if (seperate_mod == 1) {

        val = Serial.parseInt();
        shiftOut(data_g, clock_g, MSBFIRST, val);

    } else if (seperate_mod == 2) {

        val = Serial.parseInt();
        shiftOut(data_b, clock_b, MSBFIRST, val);

    }
    seperate += 1;
  }
}
```

But even more strange is that THIS CODE does work, it's only using one register:

```
#define data 2
#define clock 6
#define reset 5

void setup()
{
  pinMode(clock, OUTPUT); // make the clock pin an output
  pinMode(data , OUTPUT); // make the data pin an output
  pinMode(reset, OUTPUT);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  digitalWrite(reset, LOW);
  delay(1500);
  digitalWrite(reset, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  while(!Serial);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int val = Serial.parseInt();
    if (val > 255) {
      Serial.println("ERR: Value out of range");
    } else {
      shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, val);
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone tell me please what I am doing wrong?

---

To zmo:

```
5
5
5
5
5
>ENTERED A NUMBER<
0 ; seperate_mod = 0
1
4 ; END of conditional
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
>ENTERED A NUMBER<
0 ; seperate_mod = 1
2
4 ; END of conditional
5
5
5
5
5
5
>ENTERED A NUMBER<
0 ; seperate_mod = 2
3
4 ; END of conditional
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'The code seems to be wrong' ?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Well, in the second code, the first shift register gives an output, so it should do as well in the first code. But the code isn't controlling _any_ of the registers, so it seems like it doesn't even count. I really can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone tell me please what I am doing wrong?

your code looks mostly fine at first glance, so it's likely to be something else in the context of your code that's not going right.

- Have you tried adding debugging printout statements?
- Have you tried using a debugger (using a device such as the Atmel ICE)?

It's a sane thing to doubt yourself when what you wrote is not working the way you expect — assuming PEBCAK is often the first best answer. But then, running through your code, displaying values along the way will prove to you whether you're doing it right or wrong, and if it's wrong where is that.

Then, it feels to me like your code isn't actually running at all, either because `Serial` initialisation is blocking forever in `setup()` or because `Serial.available()` is never being true for some other reasons.

---

Can you try adding that other debug print statement:

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int seperate_mod = seperate % 3;
    Serial.print("0 ; seperate_mod = ");
    Serial.println(seperate_mod);
    if (seperate_mod == 0) {
        Serial.println("1");
        val = Serial.parseInt();
        shiftOut(data_r, clock_r, MSBFIRST, val);

    } else if (seperate_mod == 1) {

        Serial.println("2");
        val = Serial.parseInt();
        shiftOut(data_g, clock_g, MSBFIRST, val);

    } else if (seperate_mod == 2) {
        Serial.println("3");    

        val = Serial.parseInt();
        shiftOut(data_b, clock_b, MSBFIRST, val);

    }
    seperate += 1;
    Serial.println("4 ; END of conditional");
  }
  Serial.println("5");
}
```

and update your question with the resulting output?

Comment: But the code gets stuck after Serial.println(seperate_mod); (it prints it and then shiftOut does not work, so it simply re-enters the loop)

Comment: please cf my edit update your Q with necessary output